# Vuetify 3 gives a dark background on buttons, v-menu, v-select and other components on click or on hover

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I'm using Vue ^3.2.13 and Vuetify ^3.3.17. Whenever i use the v-btn or v-menu or v-select, there is a dark background on the item selected.
[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QokE.png)

This is my vuetify.ts file:

```
import { createVuetify, ThemeDefinition } from 'vuetify'
import 'vuetify/styles'
import * as components from 'vuetify/components'
import * as directives from 'vuetify/directives'
import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'
import { aliases, mdi } from 'vuetify/iconsets/mdi'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify-labs.css'

const myCustomLightTheme: ThemeDefinition = {
    dark: false,
    colors: {
        primary: '#1A9CFC',
        secondary: '#EDF7FF',
        error: '#FF2500',
        background: '#FFFFFF',
        surface: '#FFFFFF',
        info: '#2196F3',
        success: '#4CAF50',
        warning: '#FB8C00',
    },
}

const vuetify = createVuetify({
    components,
    directives,
    icons: {
        defaultSet: 'mdi',
        aliases,
        sets: {
            mdi,
        },
    },
    defaults: {
        VBtn: {
            style: 'text-transform: none;',
        },
        global: {
            ripple: false,
            attach: '#admin',
        },
    },
    theme: {
        defaultTheme: 'myCustomLightTheme',
        themes: {
            myCustomLightTheme,
        },
    },
})

export default vuetify
```

For temporary fix, i change the opacity of the overlay and the background will not be shown.

```
        ::v-deep {
            .v-btn__overlay {
                opacity: 0 !important;
                visibility: hidden !important;
                background: transparent !important;
            }
        }
```

But this is happening in most components and I'm having trouble in adding this class for every component. Has anyone else faced this issue?

Comment: My guess is you are missing the root component which provides the layout. Make sure you have `v-app` or `v-layout` surrounding your Vuetify app.

Comment: @MoritzRingler Added that, but even then the dark background exists on click or hover